# Can you solve this devilish Junior Jumble?

Tags: wordplay, anagram

In the game Undertale, there is a character named Papyrus who believes that the Jumble puzzle is much harder than the daily crossword.

Help prove him right by trying to solve this brainteaser:

[image: Title: "Jumble". First word: first and sixth boxes are shaded, scrambled letters are "N E H K T C I". Second word: fifth and eighth boxes are shaded, scrambled letters are "E T S R R I N A". Third word: first box is shaded, scrambled letters are "S L E P Y A R". Fourth word: second and fourth boxes are shaded, scrambled letters are "S A N M R P A E". Instructions: "Now unscramble the grey [shaded] squares to get the surprise answer, as suggested by the cartoon on the right". The boxes given for the final answer are two, then a dash, then five. The cartoon is a robot saying "Bone appetit! Nyeh heh heh!" at a table, one hand under a plate, while a shorter figure with a robot hand slaps themself on the head. The caption to the cartoon is "Papyrus served spaghetti as usual; it was his standard evening (blank here for answer)."]

Comment: Source: [my Twitter](https://twitter.com/lz9364/status/655269230502354944)

Comment: Are you allowing partial answers? I'm *pretty* sure of what I have for the first four, but I don't have a good answer for the punchline yet.

Comment: @Dennis: The first 4 all have multiple possibilities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The four words are

> THICKEN, RETRAINS, REPLAYS, and SPEARMAN

and the spaghetti is, of course, Papyrus' evening

> RE-PASTA. (zoom-in, ba-dum-tish)

Comment: Ding ding ding, we have a winner!

Answer (score 2):

There's a cooking-related possibility for all of the first four:

> KITCHEN, STRAINER, PARSLEY, PARMESAN

which gives this:

> KEIRPAM

Not sure what that could anagram to, though - all of the words have multiple possibilities anyway so this could be entirely wrong.

Comment: Those were my first thoughts too, but I'm thinking they're red herrings given the lack of final answer.

Comment: Good job on finding all the red herrings. :P